# 7zip: errors, problems, and questions

Tags: windows, batch-file, unzip, 7zip

i am trying to run a batch file that extracts only .jar files with 7z.exe
here is my code:

```
set location=%cd%
set filename=%location%\outputfolder
set unzip=%location\resources

cd %unzip%
7z e -o%filename% -ir!*.jar -y "%filename%\*.zip"
```

but it gives an exception: `error: incorrect command line` so i removed the `-ir!*.jar` and it then gives another error: `error: cannot use absolute pathnames for this command` so i changed the `-o%filename%` to `-oC:\outputfolder` and it works!!!!!!(here is my script now):

```
set location=%cd%
set filename=%location%\outputfolder
set unzip=%location\resources

cd %unzip%
7z e -oC:\outputfolder -y "%filename%\*.zip"
```

but i need these features
how fix?

Answer (score 1):

try it with double quotes, `%cd%` maybe has spaces:

```
7z e -o"%filename%" -i!*.jar -y "%filename%\*.zip"
```

Usage from the help screen:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Usage: 7za  [...]  [...]
       []


  a: Add files to archive
  b: Benchmark
  d: Delete files from archive
  e: Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  l: List contents of archive
  t: Test integrity of archive
  u: Update files to archive
  x: eXtract files with full paths

  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude archives
  -bd: Disable percentage indicator
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include filenames
  -m{Parameters}: set compression Method
  -o{Directory}: set Output directory
  -p{Password}: set Password
  -r[-|0]: Recurse subdirectories
  -scs{UTF-8 | WIN | DOS}: set charset for list files
  -sfx[{name}]: Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}]: read data from stdin
  -slt: show technical information for l (List) command
  -so: write data to stdout
  -ssc[-]: set sensitive case mode
  -ssw: compress shared files
  -t{Type}: Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName]: Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g]: Create volumes
  -w[{path}]: assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude filenames
  -y: assume Yes on all queries
```

[image]

Comment: @user2669763 I tested it, works fine here. I added the Help screen to my answer.

Comment: can you tell me what this is? `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` this is what is stopping 7zip from running! is there any way to unset it?

Comment: I can't see any `setlocal` in your code. `Delayed expansion`  is necessary to access  variables in `if`  and `for`  code blocks.

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422082/setlocal-enabledelayedexpansion-interrupt-setlocal-enabledelayedexpansion-set)