# SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION , Interrupt SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

`NOTE:`THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!! OF `"Temporarily interrupt SETLOCAL"`

i want to be able to `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` then do something, then `ENDLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` do something else (7z command) then `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` once again in a .bat! because 7z.exe does not allow `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. see?

code:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Echo hi!
7z e -o"C:\test" -i!*.jar "C:\*.zip"
```

output:
    `hi!`
    `Error: incorrect command line`

when i change my code to:

```
Echo hi!
7z e -o"C:\test" -i!*.jar "C:\*.zip"
```

it works!!!!!!

here is my code so far to interrupt `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Echo hi!
Endlocal
7z e -o"C:\test" -i!*.jar "C:\*.zip"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Echo hi!
```

i want to put this in a different .bat which needs `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to run

Comment: Your first. sample  outputs `hi` not `hi!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve your problem this way:

```
set bang=!
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Echo hi!
7z e -o"C:\test" -i!bang!*.jar "C:\*.zip"
```

Just be sure that the `set bang=!` command is executed when delayed expansion is disabled.

Comment: But you should also change the echo line to `echo hi!bang!`

Answer (score 1):

7zip hasn't problems with delayed expansion.
It's the exclamation mark, it will be removed from the line before 7z see it.

You only need to escape them.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Echo hi^^!
7z e -o"C:\test" -i^^!*.jar "C:\*.zip"
```